# Batch file continually resets to the start

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

I intend to use the code below to shutdown or restart a computer. Every time I run this, it goes back to `set /p var=Type computer name here:` Can you please tell me, what is wrong with my script and how to fix it?

```
@ECHO off
set /p var=Type computer name here: 
cls
TITLE %var% power control!!!!
ECHO Copyright © Joshua Reynolds 2012
ECHO USE THIS PROGRAM AT YOUR OWN RISK
pause
:start
cls
ECHO Choose an option below:
ECHO 1. Shutdown
ECHO 2. Restart
ECHO 3. Abort previous choice
ECHO 4. Exit
set /p choice=Type the options number: 
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto shutdown
if '%choice%'=='2' goto restart
if '%choice%'=='3' goto abort
if '%choice%'=='4' exit
cls
ECHO "%choice%" is not a valid option please try again
ECHO.
pause
goto start
:shutdown
COLOR 4f
cls
ECHO To shutdown %var%
pause
shutdown /s /m \\%var%
ECHO %var% should now shutdown.
goto start
:restart
COLOR A0
cls
ECHO To restart %var%
pause
shutdown /r /m \\%var%
ECHO %var% should now restart.
goto end
:abort
COLOR 5f
cls
shutdown /a /m \\%var%
goto end
:end
pause
COLOR 0f
goto start
```

Comment: You have enough echos in there. From where is is continually going back to the top of the batch? Help us help you. You need to give full details of a problem and post [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) when attempting to solve it. Otherwise you might get answers that are identical to what you have already done. It's also polite to have tried to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the name of your batch script is **shutdown.bat** and it is in your current directory. So when your script tries to run the SHUTDOWN command, it re-runs your batch script instead.

Either change the name of your script, or else explicitly use `shutdown.exe` within your script whenever you want to invoke the command.

Comment: @JoshuaReynolds - If this answer solved your problem then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer may be accepted per question. Once you reach 15 points you will have the privilege to up-vote any answer you find useful, including answers to other people's questions. An up vote awards the answer poster 10 points.